# FLEX: question about MXML syntax

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I would like to know if it is the same to assign properties to my custom component in its own class, or from the parent document. Please see snippet below:

Here I assign the property bottom in my custom component class:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:LinkButton bottom="20" >        

    <mx:Script>
...
```

Here I assign the property bottom when I use the component in my main MXML file

```
<myComp:Brick bottom="10"/>
```

Am I overriding the original one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The one which you gave in the main MXML will get applied.

Answer (score 1):

You don't override in the sense of oop, but you reassign the value of the property to a new value, yes.